# How to send data from Django to outside python class or vice versa?

Tags: python, django, oop

in my app folder I have `views.py` and `bot.py`.
The bot.py is main brain of my project, there are all my functions that 'do' main stuff(backend). I import them and use in Django. Now somehow I need to send data from django to bot.py. How to do that? I have:

views.py:

```
bot = Instagram()

class InstabotFormView(AjaxFormMixin, FormView):
    form_class = LoginInstagramForm
    template_name = 'instabot.html'
    success_url = 'runinstabot.html'

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(InstabotFormView, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(InstabotFormView, self).form_valid(form)
        login = form.cleaned_data.get('login')
        password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        tagi = form.cleaned_data.get('tags')
        tags = []
        tagi = tagi.split(',')
        tags.extend(tagi)
        print(tags)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print('It is AJAX')
            bot.login(login,password)
            bot.search(tags)
            print(form.cleaned_data)
            data = {
                'message': "Succesfully  opened Selenium."
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response
```

---

bot.py:

```
class Instagram(object):
...

 def search(self,tags):
        time.sleep(1)
        search = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input')
        search.clear()
        search.send_keys(tags[self.nextTag], Keys.ENTER)
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '/html/body/span/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[1]/div').click()

    def changeTag(self):
        #if a list gets to the end reset it
        self.nextTag += 1
        tagsNum = len(Instagram.tags)
        if self.nextTag == tagsNum:
            self.nextTag = 0
        else:
            self.tags[0 + self.nextTag]
        return  self.nextTag
```

After I run my script it writes:

```
AttributeError: 'Instagram' object has no attribute 'tags'
```

I know that `Instagram.tags` does not exist but how to use data from Django inside my `bot.py`? How to put instead of `Instagram.tags` , `tags=[]` from my Django class? Or is there a better solution?(maybe writing changeTag() in Django and returning data to bot.py?)

I have tried importing Django class inside bot.py but does not work

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do here. What do you want `Instagram.tags` to actually do? Without understanding that I don't see how we can help you. (And also you need to show where you are calling `changeTag` plus the code for `search`).

Comment: thank you for reply. I have added search. I wanted to avoid adding all code as it is long. Generaly my script run instagram, search by tags which i enter due to Django forms then it download certain photos. After 10 downloads it change for next tag(changeTag). My problem is that I enter data by Django forms. I am writting a list in Django (tags=[]) using: tagi = form.cleaned_data.get('tags'). I have dificulties with sending that data to bot.py. My list is present in Django but can not import to bot.py

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Django. You’re just dealing with Python classes. Classes define properties and methods for their instances. So if you initialize an instance of `Instagram` inside another object (a `InstabotFormView`) you can just assign values/objects to its properties.

Now if you add the `tags = []` property to `Instagram` (initializing it with empty lost) then inside Django class you can set `bot.tags` to the tags and use that inside the `Intagram` methods.

Comment: thank you for reply. This is what I did. But I have problem with initalizing InstabotFormView inside Instagram

Comment: But that is the wrong way round. As Dirk says, you need to instantiate your Instagram class inside the view.

Comment: In MVC (Model-View-Controller) paradigm, your `Instagram` class is a Model (just not a Django model, because it isn't saved to database). Your `InstabotFormView` is a Controller (django views take the role of controllers, a bit confusingly). A Model should never ever have to deal with a controller, so you should never have to initialise your `InstabotFormView` inside your `Instagram` model. Do it the other way round: your controller instantiates the model and sends messages to the model by calling its methods.

Comment: ok, very good and simple answer. Now I understand, so I will try to figure out how to send data from my controler to a Model. Thank you